# how to get Checkbox isChecked data from recyclerview in Kotlin

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin

I want to get isChecked data from checkbox from recycler view in this I am using Binding Adapter but I am not getting how to do that. If anyone has a way to do that then please share it.

```
    class ItemListAdapter(private val itemDeleteListener: ItemDeleteListener,
private val checkItemListener: CheckItemListener) :
    ListAdapter<ListItemTable, ItemListAdapter.ViewHolder>(ListItemDiffCallBack()) {

    class ViewHolder(private val binding: ShowItemBinding) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(binding.root) {

        fun bind(listItemTable: ListItemTable, itemDeleteListener: ItemDeleteListener,
                 checkItemListener: CheckItemListener) {
            binding.itemHistory = listItemTable
            binding.itemDelete = itemDeleteListener
            binding.checkItem = checkItemListener

            binding.executePendingBindings()
        }

        companion object {
            fun from(parent: ViewGroup): ViewHolder {
                val layoutInflater = LayoutInflater.from(parent.context)
                val binding = ShowItemBinding.inflate(layoutInflater, parent, false)
                return ViewHolder(binding)
            }
        }
    }

    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): ViewHolder {
        return ViewHolder.from(parent)
    }

    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: ViewHolder, position: Int) {
        holder.bind(getItem(position), itemDeleteListener, checkItemListener)

        getItem(position).itemCompleted
    }

    class ItemDeleteListener(val clickListener: (listId: Long) -> Unit) {
        fun onClick(listItemTable: ListItemTable) = clickListener(listItemTable.itemId)
    }

    class CheckItemListener(val clickListener: (listId: Long) -> Unit){
        fun onClick(listItemTable: ListItemTable) = clickListener(listItemTable.itemId)
    }

    class ListItemDiffCallBack : DiffUtil.ItemCallback<ListItemTable>() {
        override fun areItemsTheSame(oldItem: ListItemTable, newItem: ListItemTable): Boolean {
            return oldItem.itemId == newItem.itemId
        }

        override fun areContentsTheSame(oldItem: ListItemTable, newItem: ListItemTable): Boolean {
            return oldItem == newItem
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Could you show the code for your binding adapter, and elaborate a bit more about what you're trying to achieve? I assume you know about `CheckBox.isChecked` property.

Answer (score 1):

See: https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/data-binding/two-way

If you're using data binding I think you should take a look at two-way data binding. It's even introduced through this checkbox problem inside the docs, so you're in luck!

Edit: To be a bit more specific you would implement this like so:

#### Create a binding adapter that sets the property on the view

```xml
<layout>
<data>
  <variable
    name="itemHistory"
    type="your.package.ListItemTable" />
  <variable
    name="checkItem"
    type="android.widget.CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener" />
  <!-...->
</data>
<CheckBox
    android:id="@+id/rememberMeCheckBox"
    android:checked="@{itemHistory.itemCompleted}"
    android:onCheckedChanged="@{checkItem}"
/>
</layout>
```

So you have to use [OnCheckedChangeListener](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener) instead of your own listener, and pass that to your xml.

Comment: I already visited that page, and the solution is fine also but how this is going to work in the recycler view.

Comment: @ShubhamTater I've updated my answer for you

Answer (score 0):

You already have 2 "listeners" on your constructor of the adapter and you are passing them to the view holder by using the `bind` method.

```
class ItemListAdapter(private val itemDeleteListener: ItemDeleteListener, private val checkItemListener: CheckItemListener)
```

So you have to pass the correct one to your view holder and then set the checkbox listener. Is better to use the constructor of the view holder to avoid passing the same listener on every binding

```
class ViewHolder(private val binding: ShowItemBinding, private val itemDeleteListener: ItemDeleteListener, private val checkItemListener: CheckItemListener) { 

    fun bind(listItemTable: ListItemTable) {

            binding.YOUR_CHECKBOX.setOnCheckedChangeListener(null) 
           
            binding.itemHistory = listItemTable
            binding.itemDelete = itemDeleteListener
            binding.checkItem = checkItemListener

            binding.executePendingBindings()
            
            binding.YOUR_CHECKBOX.setOnCheckedChangeListener { -, isChecked ->  
                //here call your "listener" by example
                checkItemListener.theMethod(isChecked)
            }
        }

}
```

We set the checkbox listener to null first so we can stop listening and then set the view values, otherwise, anything changing the view will also trigger the listener, once the view values are set, then set the checkbox listener to trigger the callbacks.